# получить размер картинки из переменной

Tags: php

getimagesize(), ожидает путь до файла, а у меня строка в переменной и т.к. файлов на обработку будет много жалко диск гонять, может можно как-то переменную подсунуть getimagesize() не сохраняя картинку на диск?

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = file_get_contents('Z:\qecode.png');
$w = getimagesizefromstring($q);
print_r($w);
```